# The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, process

I want to start notepad, using a filename the user chose from a document list I already provided using `Process.Start`.
When I use that method it is throwing the error "The system cannot find the file specified".

My code:

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepath.exe";
 startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\folder\a.txt";
 Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Are you looking for notepad.exe not notepath.exe?

Comment: I think in asp.net, we do server mapping by calling Server.MapPath() something. I am not sure what exactly is the name of function. You can't use this mapping in an ASP.NET application

Comment: i think you mean `notepad.exe` ? Also won't just reading the file and displaying the contents do for you

Comment: Make sure the files *C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepath.exe* and *C:\folder\a.txt* exist on your computer.

Comment: Note for reviewers: IMO, the 'possible duplicate' above has nothing to do with this question (issue there is spaces in filename, issue here is probably incorrect exe name)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepath.exe");
```

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369119/error-in-process-start-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) for further details

Comment: wonder how this is different nonetheless you forgot the argument

Answer (score 0):

*"I want to show document list that is in a folder with using 'process.start' method."* That is simply wrong.

To list files present in a folder, use [`Directory.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx)

Comment: i show list(using directory.getfiles..) when a user select the list item, i want to show document with using process.start(..)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
By doing this you also makes sure that your file will appear even if the path contains whitespacing

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe",
        Arguments = $"\"{filePath}\"",
    }
};
proc.Start();
```

*You used notepath.exe, I think you would like to use notepad.exe, therefore I changed the executables name!