# Cannot run python SImpleHTTPServer on windows 10 for d3.js testing (issue changing environment variable)

Tags: windows, python-2.7, d3.js

I just installed python 2.7 on a windows machine to start SimpleHTTPServer in order to test my d3.js code.

Normally on my linux laptop I would start a terminal window in the folder where my files are (index.html, data.json, etc). However, if I do the same on windows it doesn't work.

The only way to make this works is when I run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`in the python installation folder (in my case C:\Python27).

I read here that I need to set the python environment variable. The screen shows what I have done. As you can see I set the variable both locally (for the current user) and system-wide. However, when I try to run a `python`command out of the installation folder nothing changes.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `python` variable is incorrect - rather you should add the python executable path to the `PATH` environment variable e.g.

```
PATH=C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;
```

You should then be able to call `python` from anywhere.

Indeed any path you include in the `PATH` will then allow you to call executables in that path without specifying the full path or extension.

i.e.

`C:\Python27\python.exe` becomes `python`

`C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe` becomes `cmd`

For more detail see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable) or my answer to this question: [Error in Process.Start() -- The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369119/error-in-process-start-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified/18253825#18253825)